# "CRON: Module is unknown" after upgrading to 10.04

Tags: 10.04, cron, pam

I just upgraded our server to Ubuntu 10.04 and `cron` just stopped working. I tried to restart the server, restart `cron` but nothing worked for me. It just reports in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May 12 16:32:01 uhor CRON[8424]: Module is unknown
May 12 16:33:01 uhor CRON[8430]: Module is unknown
May 12 16:33:01 uhor CRON[8429]: Module is unknown
May 12 16:34:01 uhor CRON[8432]: Module is unknown
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong? Some people were reporting also `Module is unknown` error after upgrading but it was usually with `passwd` command, not with `cron`.

This is my /etc/pam.d/cron

```
#
# The PAM configuration file for the cron daemon
#

@include common-auth

# Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment
# and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session       required   pam_env.so

# In addition, read system locale information
session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
# Sets up user limits, please define limits for cron tasks
# through /etc/security/limits.conf
# session    required   pam_limits.so
```

I guess there might be something wrong with my pam_* files, but I tried to reinstall them and it didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

This is [a bug caused by a security update](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/790538).

The solution is to restart cron: `sudo service cron restart`

Do an upgrade, a fix is already available.

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` - The fix is already available.

Comment: Too bad that Martin doesn't seem to be coming back to accept; +1 from me. Googling only turned up postings from 2006-2008.

Comment: I ran upgrade today but it didn't help. Still `Module is unknown` ...